# Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.)

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv3.1

I want any advice how to solve this Error

I'm trying a sample code to check the opencv_contrib Extra modules using CMake

This is the error message:

[image]

And this is the sample code which I used

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void*);

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread("Baraya.jpg", 1);

    /// Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

    /// Create Window
    char* source_window = "Source";
    namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(source_window, src);

    createTrackbar(" Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback);
    thresh_callback(0, 0);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void*)
{
    Mat threshold_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    /// Detect edges using Threshold
    threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    /// Find contours
    findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    vector<Point2f>center(contours.size());
    vector<float>radius(contours.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
        minEnclosingCircle((Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i]);
    }


    /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
        rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
        circle(drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0);
    }

    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the code you posted. It works well if you installed OpenCV properly. This error is because you didn't build with any windowing system .

This error is from  [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/f820df2ea08ebc55fcfa7203c2b35a2c991a3e75/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp#L494):

```
#if   defined (HAVE_WIN32UI)  // see window_w32.cpp
#elif defined (HAVE_GTK)      // see window_gtk.cpp
#elif defined (HAVE_COCOA)    // see window_carbon.cpp
#elif defined (HAVE_CARBON)
#elif defined (HAVE_QT)       // see window_QT.cpp
#elif defined (WINRT) && !defined (WINRT_8_0) // see window_winrt.cpp

#else

// No windowing system present at compile time ;-(
//
// We will build place holders that don't break the API but give an error
// at runtime. This way people can choose to replace an installed HighGUI
// version with a more capable one without a need to recompile dependent
// applications or libraries.

void cv::setWindowTitle(const String&, const String&)
{
    CV_Error(Error::StsNotImplemented, "The function is not implemented. "
        "Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. "
        "If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script");
}
```

---

So re-run CMAKE with `WITH_WIN32UI`, since you are on Windows, and eventually with `WITH_QT`.